# How do I split a list of names (with title and surname) where they are only separated by a space?

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I have a blob of text that I need to split up with a list of Titles and Surnames contained therein. They are all separated by spaces, there are no carriage returns at all.

For example:

> Mr Smith Mr Johnson Mrs Johnson Ms Smith 
>   and so on and so on

I need to break these up into individual names so that I have something like the following

> [0] = Mr Smith 
>   [1] = Mr Johnson 
>   [2] = Mrs Johnson 
>   [3] = Ms Smith

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using the .NET framework C# (just in case that is useful to someone).

Comment: That is not a good format to keep data. What about doctors, knights, lords, clergy, foreigners, etc?

Comment: @Kobi: Having seen enormous amounts of complexity in human names over the years, I suspect that the right approach involves using an XML mixed content content model to mark up a full name with the semantics of various parts, allowing bits to be elided based on target formality level. That's a vastly complex way of doing it! But I think it's probably the minimum that will actually work properly. Of course, nobody does it that way and so there must be a lot of bad code out there…

Comment: Required reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try

```
var result = Regex.Split(input, @" (?=Mr\b|Mrs\b|Ms\b)", RegexOptions.None);
```

if every title is indeed one of "Mr", "Mrs", or "Ms". This approach allows for quite a lot of unusual surnames, but needs to know every title in advance. See it in action at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Otnf1)

Comment: Nice; that'll deal with some truly tricky cases provided the list of titles is comprehensive enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
string[] parts =
  Regex.Matches(myarray[0], "([^\s]*\s[^\s]*)(?:\s |$)")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: I have a colleague whose family name is two words, even without the title. Real world data is nasty!

Comment: I won't mention my colleague's name — hardly fair to them — but consider [`Graf von Zeppelin`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_von_Zeppelin), which fits the title+surname pattern. (Bonus: the Graf is a long dead historical figure and won't complain at being an example.)